# Database link objects within objects C#

Tags: c#, node.js, database, object, umbraco

I know it's seems like a very newbie question but it's still confuse me how you can link objects within objects:

For example I have an objects of Book:

```
name
pages
publication Date
author
```

and so on.

But my question will be on the `Author` itself is an object so how will I be able to link author to this book inside the database I mean One `Author` can have a lot of books so it's not right to save to every book the full author object.

Thanks for your help

I tried to look for any answer on Stack Overflow, but it seems to be a concept relatively simple but not for me.

Comment: You'd normally have an identifier column in the Author table, and then a column in the Book table where the value is the identifier. It then gets more complicated if an author can have multiple books - at that point you need a third table to store book-id/author-id pairs. I suggest you search for "sql one to many" to find lots of articles about this.

Comment: what `RDMS` you're using? `ORM`?

Comment: @odaiwa I use Umbraco

Comment: Thanks  @JonSkeet I will try to read about that, what I'm trying to do then it's how to make a good GET method that will include both Author and Book

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, you need two separate tables. `Book` and `Author` tables represent two objects. The `Book` table has a  column for author name (it would be unique), and the `Author` table has the Author object class members. The rest is up to you to use the author's name as a foreign key in the `Book` table to join them later in a query or get the author's name from the Book object and search the `Author` table for the rest authors' properties.